# Serving static content on a POST using express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, express

I'm trying to serve static content for a facebook app using `express.js`

```
app.configure(function (){
    app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});
```

This works on a `GET` however on a `POST` I get a `404` saying `Cannot POST /`

```
curl -X POST localhost:3001
Cannot POST /
```

How can I get around this?

---

Based on zerkms's answer I came up with this hack, which I imagine is quite bad practice.

```
app.post('/', function(req, res, next){

    try {
        if(req.url === '/'){
            req.method = 'GET'  
        }
    } catch(err){
        res.send(500, err)
        res.end()
    }
    next()
});

app.configure(function (){
    app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});
```

This works but I'd still like a better solution if anyone has one.

Comment: What errors are you getting? Is it a 404? A 500? Is your program crashing?

Comment: Why are you treating a POST like a GET in the first place?

Comment: Because, as far as I can tell, if you want to make facebook display a web app, it will only make requests for said web app with a POST.

Comment: @Loourr: "it will only make requests for said web app with a POST" --- this doesn't sound correct

Comment: Based on these questions [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12005442/express-static-cannot-response-to-post-requests), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18326888/how-to-get-post-files-in-express-static) I believe it is.

Answer (score 2):

It only serves `GET` or `HEAD` requests.

See https://github.com/expressjs/serve-static/blob/master/index.js#L51

```
if ('GET' != req.method && 'HEAD' != req.method) return next();
```

Comment: Is there some other way to server static content with a post?

Comment: @Loourr: I honestly don't know. Never worked with node.js, just opened their repository and found why it doesn't serve through `POST` :-D

Comment: Hmm, well thanks for the help anyway. It helped me figure out a hack which seems to be working.